# Frustrating, often occurring with all browsers - having to reload pages to view them

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, anti-virus, anti-spyware

I have a frustrating problem.. frustrating because it is often happening but I don't know how to fix it.

However, I just came across a good way of illustrating it.

*So far the main symptom has been web pages half loading (meaning css not getting applied and mostly unreadable.. pressing reload one or 2 times will fix that, but as you can imagine it is annoying)*

But I just found a better way to show what is going on.

First to let you know I have windows 10 anniversary update. I am not sure if it started as soon as I installed that or just before it. It could be caused by windows itself or some software I installed? (but can't remember) or my router?? (just a guess - router worked fine before, but I did disable WPS some weeks ago since it blocks inter-computer on the same LAN communication, i.e. I couldn't control KODI from another computer with it enabled - or even ping KODI's box)

*Whatever it is, it affects all browsers. chrome, firefox, edge.*

Both with the reloading problem and with this new "all music" example.

I had uninstalled my chrome ad blocker a while back and I have no system level add blocker (that I know of installed, i.e. not a specific program for it. However, I wonder if it might be part of some anti-virus or tool program.. I do have [Glary Utilities Pro](http://www.glarysoft.com/glary-utilities-pro/) installed. Lots of tools in there)

So, what happens with All Music? I get this screenshot with all 3 browsers:

[image: All Music AD Block Detection]

So, then I used a Web Proxy... and voila, I got through. No ad block detected:

[image: Web Proxy - No Ad Blocker detected]

So, what's going on? I have no idea. Anyone have any thoughts.

I also disabled Avast's web shield and home networking securtity components. But that didn't help.

### UPDATE

- I have eliminated any thought that the router can be the problem. Since ads show up on my non-rooted, non-ad-blocked cell phone
- My windows 10 laptop however, appears to have universal ad blocking. No browser can show ads.
- So my question is, what kinds of software should I be looking for?
- or do you think that somehow it is not software, that somehow some files were appended with a list of ad sites to block - and the software that did that has been uninstalled a long time ago?
- I really was thinking it was avast - but, I don't think there are av programs in the business of blocking ads and also I disabled web shield and LAN protection
- I also do run occasionally malware bytes free and spybot free, but since they are free they run on demand only - not in the background

Comment: I see you tagged this with [wireless-router]. What kind of special routing or programs are you running on the wireless router? How does it come into play in the question? Does it work if you only use wired?

Comment: It's just a linkysys, the only reason was because I noticed this started happening sometime after I disabled WPS - i guess I'll remove the tag, I don't really see how disabling WPS would do that.

Comment: huh, it does appear I have a phantom ad blocker running - because all browsers block ads, but I can't figure out what is doing that. it's not Avast I think. It's not an extension because Edge has 0 extensions installed. And I didn't explicitly install any software to block ads.